# Azure CloudBlobContainer.ListBlobs

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to update a command line utility someone else wrote years ago so that it will compile on current versions of Azure SDK.  The breaking changes are biting me, especially on `ListBlobs()` method of CloudBlobContainer.

He constructed a `BlobRequestOptions` as follows:

```
BlobRequestOptions options = new BlobRequestOptions
{
    UseFlatBlobListing = true,
    BlobListingDetails = BlobListingDetails.Snapshots,
    AccessCondition = AccessCondition.IfNotModifiedSince(fetchParams.EndDate),
    RetryPolicy = RetryPolicies.Retry(10, RetryPolicies.DefaultClientBackoff),
    DeleteSnapshotsOption = DeleteSnapshotsOption.None
};
```

Obviously `UseFlatBlobListing` and `BlobListingDetails` are now just params to `ListBlobs()`.  And I don't think I have to be concerned with `DeleteSnapshotsOption` now.

But I don't see how to specify the above `AccessCondition`, and that is a critical parameter.

Also, I don't know what `RetryPolicies.DefaultClientBackoff` used to do, and I don't see a similar name in the new `RetryPolicy` stuff.

Anyone have any advice on this?

Answer (score 4):

Even with the older library, `AccessCondition` parameter was ignored when listing blobs. As you may already know, `AccessCondition` provides a mechanism for performing conditional operations (like delete blob only if it has not been modified since yesterday etc.) and is applicable only for certain operations. For a list of operations which can be performed only if certain conditions are matched, please see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179371.aspx. So as far as listing blobs are concerned, I would say don't worry about the access conditions as it is not applicable in this particular operation.

Retry policies, as the name suggests allows you to instruct storage client library to retry an operation in case a `transient error` occurs. In version 2.0, retry policies have moved into a separate namespace: [`Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.RetryPolicies`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.retrypolicies.aspx).

I wrote some blog posts on migrating code from older storage client library to version 2.0. I think these two posts may be useful to you in the context of your question:

**Storage Client Library 2.0 – Migrating Blob Storage Code**: http://gauravmantri.com/2012/11/28/storage-client-library-2-0-migrating-blob-storage-code/

**Storage Client Library 2.0 – Implementing Retry Policies**: http://gauravmantri.com/2012/12/30/storage-client-library-2-0-implementing-retry-policies/

Comment: So, from what I can gather, it is not possible to retrieve a filtered set of blobs (ignoring prefix, which I can't use because it's of no value in my case to filter by file name).  Instead I must retrieve all of them and THEN filter. Correct?

Comment: That's correct. Blob storage does not support querying capabilities. As you mentioned you would need to filter it on the client side.

Comment: Ok, thanks. You might think they would offer that for performance reasons, but maybe it's just me.